# GAE python display multiple images in on page

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to display multiple images (pulled from datastore) in one page.

Doing this only displays 1 image...

```
class Stocks(db.Model):
   ticker = db.StringProperty()
   picture = db.BlobProperty(default=None)
```

What i use to serve:

```
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/jpeg'
self.response.out.write(stock.picture)
```

Is this the only way i can server the picture?
Can i do it in a way where i do multiple image response outs?
Something along the lines like this.

```
 self.response.out.write('<img src=' + stock.picture + '>')
```

---

UPDATE: Thanks for the reply.  Totally didn't know you could do something like that.

So i did this:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/dailystocks', frontend_dailyStocks),('/image/.*', ServeImage),('/mainPage', MainPage)], debug=True)
```

Then this:

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    images = Stocks.all().fetch(100)
    html = ['<img src="/image/%s" />' % img.key() for img in images]
    self.response.out.write(html)    

class ServeImage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    key = self.request.get('key')
    image = Stocks.get(key)
    if image:
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/jpeg'
        self.response.out.write(image.picture)
    else:
        self.abort(404)
```

The thing loaded but it showed a list of broken image links.

This is an example image link:

```
    http://*****.appspot.com/image/ag9zfmpwZ2V0bGlzdGluZ3NyEwsSBlN0b2NrcxiAgICAwOGGCAw
```

Comment: the thing to remember is you only get one: self.response.out.write

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each picture you want to serve, you'll need a separate HTTP call. So you may write a handler to serve an image, much like you suggested, as follows:

```
class ServeImage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    key = self.request.get('key')
    image = Stocks.get(key)
    if image:
      self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/jpeg'
      self.response.out.write(image.picture)
    else:
      self.abort(404)
```

Then in your main handler, load the images and render the html, referencing the ServeImage handler in each img tag ...

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    images = Stocks.all().fetch(100)
    html = ['<img src="/image?key=%s" />' % img.key() for img in images]
    self.response.out.write(html)
```

You'll need to route the url /image to your ServeImage handler.

Comment: No. The parameter to the WSGIApplication constructor is a list of tuples. You'll need to add another tuple to the list.

Comment: yeah, the pictures still showed up as a list of broken images...
['brokenImageicon', 'brokenImageicon']

Comment: Is the ServeImage handler being called?

Comment: Invalid string key . Details: 
image = Stocks.get(key)

Comment: Yes, it's being called.  The line image = Stocks.get(key) is the one that's not going through properly.  Should the line for MainPage be something like this: html = ['<img src="/image?key=%s" />' % img.key() for img in images]

Comment: html = ['<img src="/image?key=%s" />' % img.key() for img in images] fails to load as well but no error in the logs this time.

Comment: I also found another typo on self.response.out.write(stock.picture) and already replaced it with self.response.out.write(image.picture)
Does it need the self.response.headers for each of the image?

Comment: can't comment any further without seeing your code. i've explained the concept. you need to debug your code and figure out whats up. you can call the ImageHandler directly, so maybe try that first so see if its returning images. For example type http://*****.appspot.com/image/[key] in your browser address bar - does it display an image? Maybe there is no data in the blob?

Comment: it returns the self.abort(404)

Comment: DONE!!! The problem was url /image/.* to your ServeImage handler. Instead of /image/.*, i did /image.  Thanks so much Gwyn!!!!!

Comment: hooray! got there in the end!